# Is there how I can treat the error Is a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

```
#Defining the directories to the file
train_image_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Skin_Disease/train_images"#Path(".../Skin_Disease/train_images")
train_annotation_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Skin_Disease/train"#Path(".../Skin_Disease/train")

test_image_path = Path("./Skin_Disease/test_images")
test_annotation_path = Path("./Skin_Disease/test")

valid_image_path = Path("./Skin_Disease/valid_images")
valid_annotation_path = Path("./Skin_disease/valid")

#walking through the training directory to get list files

def filelist(root, file_type):
    return [os.path.join(directory_path, f) for directory_path, directory_name,
            files in os.walk(root) for f in files if f.endswith(file_type)]

#creating a dataframe to view the read files 
def generate_train_df (anno_path):
    annotations = filelist(anno_path, '.xml')
    anno_list = []
    for annotation in annotations:
        root = ET.parse(anno_path).getroot()
        anno = {}
        anno["filename"] = Path(str(train_image_path) + '/' + root.find("./filename").text)
        anno["width"] = root.find("./size/width").text
        anno["height"] = root.find("./size/height").text
        anno["xmin"] = int(root.find("./object/bndbox/xmin").text)
        anno["ymin"] = int(root.find("./object/bndbox/ymin").text)
        anno["xmax"] = int(root.find("./object/bndbox/xmax").text)
        anno["ymax"] = int(root.find("./object/bndbox/ymax").text)
        anno_list.append(anno)
        #print(anno)
    return pd.DataFrame(anno_list)


df_train = generate_train_df(train_annotation_path)
print(df_train.shape)
df_train.head()
#print(df_train)
```

The error am getting:

```
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b80f473b0929> in <module>()
----> 1 df_train = generate_train_df(train_annotation_path)
      2 print(df_train.shape)
      3 df_train.head()
      4 #print(df_train)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(self, source, parser)
    584         close_source = False
    585         if not hasattr(source, "read"):
--> 586             source = open(source, "rb")
    587             close_source = True
    588         try:

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/Skin_Disease/train'
```

Am trying to do Bounding box prediction using pytorch. My annotation is in xml format and they are placed inside a folder. In the above code am trying to walk through  the folder and am picking the elements in the annotation I need and appending it to a list in order to view in a dataframe but am getting the above error. I think the error is a result of the path but am referencing it well but maybe it's not the accepted path I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the entries in your training file list is a directory.

You can fix this error by simply excluding directory paths from your training files list:

```
def filelist(root, file_type):
    flist = [os.path.join(directory_path, f) for directory_path, directory_name,
            files in os.walk(root) for f in files if f.endswith(file_type)]

    return [path for path in flist if not os.path.isdir(path)]
```